# Emulator is loaded, but app is not installed and no error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device, helios

Emulator is loaded, but app is not installed,
I have tried restarting adb, restarting eclipse, creating new android projects, creating new avd
everthing works like normal, but I couldn't install any app at all. Below is my xml file. thanks for your help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.eldorado.myfirstapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.eldorado.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Here is android console

```
[2013-03-11 21:55:20 - MySecondProject] ------------------------------
[2013-03-11 21:55:20 - MySecondProject] Android Launch!
[2013-03-11 21:55:20 - MySecondProject] adb is running normally.
[2013-03-11 21:55:20 - MySecondProject] Performing com.exapmple.mysecondproject.MainActivity activity launch        
[2013-03-11 21:55:20 - MySecondProject] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'Gingerbread_WVGA'   is not available. Launching new emulator.
```

[2013-03-11 21:55:20 - MySecondProject] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device      'Gingerbread_WVGA'
   [2013-03-11 21:55:28 - Emulator] emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
    [2013-03-11 21:55:28 - Emulator]

Comment: Please see your `Android Console` and paste here to see what happens there!

Answer (score 0):

Check the VD you created with any API , or change android:minSdkVersion="10"  to android:minSdkVersion="7" and try again .

Comment: I changed the minsdkversion, but I still have the problem. and by the way what do you mean by VD

Comment: By the way my LogCat is quite empty, any suggestion?